# postgres rds slow response time

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have an aws rds postgres db od type t3.micro.
I am running simple queries on a pretty small table and I get pretty high response time - around 2 seconds per query run.

- Query example:
  select * from package where id='late-night';
- The cpu usage is not high (around 5%)
- We tried creating a bigger rds db (t3.meduiom) with the snapshot of the original one and the performance did not improve at all.
- Table size 2600 rows
- We examined connection with bot external ip and internal ip.
- Disk size 20gib
- Memory type: ssd

Is there a way to improve performance??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It difficult to determine where the issue it.  With 2600 rows the database should be faster but a t3.micro is a pretty small environment.  Have you used the PostgreSQL [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) command to show what the DB is doing?  Where is the client hosted (for example over a slow internet link?)  Is this in a VPC with a gateway?  There are many variables here - some additional information is needed.

Comment: hi @stdunbar thanks for responding!
t3.micro is indeed a small instance, but as i mentioned I also tried replicating the db with a bigger instance and it didn't affect the performance. The client is indeed hosted in a vpc with a gateway.

Comment: Could you just check response time for "select 1;"?

Comment: Hi @UmutTEKİN and got Total query runtime: 372 msec.

Comment: So, how many rows did your query return? As the @stdunbar state, it is better to check  execution plan and share it here. 372 msec delay can be huge depending on the purpose.

Comment: Also, could you please share response time for "select * from package limit 650;" and "select * from package limit 1300;"?